# Reducer Props getting changed in the component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

In my React app, I have a redux reducer which sends a List as props to my component.
I copy the prop to local state, and show as drop down. User changes the Dropdown so my local state changes. 
On click of cancel , I am calling redux Toastr which triggers a method to reset my state with the original props.list. But for some reason the props.list also changed similar to my state change. With my knowledge i thought props passed to the componeent will not be changed until again i call action creator.

Anyone faced similar issue? or i am doing something wrong 
Sorry for not posting the code, which I will prepare a demo if needed. Thanks!

Comment: Please post the demo for your code asap :)

Comment: Posting some code always helps the community to extend the right help, please post some code.

Comment: How are you copy props? If you just assign props to state you create reference from state to props. JavaScript not copy objects, but assign reference. You can try `Object.assign` and see if it helps

Comment: Thx Fyodor, that is the exact issue. It worked

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is an anti-pattern as you are breaking react's rule of single source of truth. You can't hold state internally in a component that is tied up with your redux state and expect it work smoothly. A similar issue of breaking the single source of truth arise when using solely `React` without `Redux` and when you try to pass props as state. In this case there is a new lifecycle hook `static getDerivedStateFromProps` but even this hook is advised to be used sparsely you can read about it  [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html?utm_source=caibaojian.com#static-getderivedstatefromprops). So if your intent is to reset state back to it's original value, you can either:

1. Use `static getDerivedStateFromProps` (which is reserved mostly for UI)
2. Use a key prop which will reset you back to your initial state
3. Use a memoization helper such as `memoize-one`